# I need to get the field value using jquery in odoo 9

Tags: jquery, odoo-9

I would like to get the xml field value using jquery in odoo 9

I have a field as text box in xml file
 and my code is:

```
<record id="shortcut_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">keybord.form</field>
        <field name="model">pos.shortcut</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Pierce_shortcut">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <t t-name="PosConfig">
                            <group>
                                <field  class="payment" name="payment"/>
                                <field name="select_customer" class="select_customer" />
                                <field name="back" class="price" />
                            </group>
                        </t>
                    </group>

                </sheet>

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

**If i enter the value in Text box it should print near text box using inner html in onchange event in jquery**
and my template xml file for insert js file:

```
<template id="PosConfig" name="pierce_ pos_backend"
        inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript"
                src="/pierce_pos_keyboard_shortcuts/static/src/js/pos_config.js"></script>
        </xpath> 
    </template>
```

**how to write  js code**

Thanks.